# Processing lists in Python compared to Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, mapreduce, list-comprehension

Having some Ruby experience, I started to learn Python and map list transformation techniques (select/map/reduce) to Python.
Let’s say I want to take a list [0..99],  square even numbers and summarize it.

In Python:

```
arr = range(100)
res = [x*x for x in arr if x % 2 == 0]
res = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, res)
```

In Ruby

```
(0..99)
  .select {|num| num % 2 == 0}
  .map {|num| num*num}
  .inject {|sum, n| sum + n}
```

So far in Python it looks fine and idiomatic.
Now, let’s say I want to throw in more mapping/filtering, saying that after I square even numbers, I want to take those divisible by 10, then divide them by 100, then select odd numbers.

In Ruby it scales well into:

```
(0..99)
  .select {|num| num % 2 == 0}
  .map {|num| num*num}
  .select {|num| num % 10 == 0}
  .map {|num| num / 100}
  .select {|num| num % 2 != 0}
  .inject {|sum, n| sum + n}
```

In Python the code becomes like so:

```
arr = range(100)
res = [x*x for x in arr if x % 2 == 0]
res = [x for x in res if x % 100 == 0]
res = [x / 100 for x in res]
res = [x for x in res if x % 2 != 0]
res = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, res)
```

It feels like the Python code here is not idiomatic and not efficient (I could nest it, but it would become unreadable).
Also code in Ruby could be easily modified for lazy evaluation which I can't say about the Python code.
How do I express this idea and a well readable and efficient code in Python?

Comment: What makes the second example seem less idiomatic and efficient than the first? They seem about equal to me.

Comment: @Kwarrtz What makes it less idiomatic and efficient is the fact that we break the chaining of the streams and assign each step to a variable. This should prevent the interpreter (IMHO) from optimizing the code. But I am just guessing here.

Comment: well, inlining the comprehensions should fix that issue.

Comment: @Kwarrtz Right, but it would make the code less readable.

Comment: Your question is very opinion-based as you're comparing apples and oranges. The best solution is to read the style-guides for both languages, and write accordingly.

Comment: @theTinMan With all due respect, I don't think that asking a question about an acceptable and idiomatic way of expressing some idea in a different language is opinion based or comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Even more idiomatic Ruby would be to use this as the even test: `a.select(&:even?)`.  Also, I believe that all your `/ 100` operations will result in zero; is that what you wanted?  If you use `/ 100.0` instead you will get a decimal fraction.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone's definition of readable code differs. Personally, I find this to be fairly readable (for a one-liner at least) and reduces a lot of unnecessary comprehensions:

```
sum([(x*x) / 100 for x in range(100) if not x*x % 100 and (x*x) / 100 % 2])
```

You could clean this up some more:

```
f = lambda x: (x*x) / 100
sum([f(x) for x in range(100) if not x*x % 100 and f(x) % 2])
```

This is maybe ~10 extra characters longer than one of the comprehensions in the question. Reduces 6 lines into 2 and four list comprehensions into a single comprehension.

Comment: Good example, thanks! Maybe my example was a bit contrived, but my point was that if you keep adding more and more filtering/mapping it quickly gets hard to optimize.